# Number of edges in randomly induced graph

Tags: probability, random-graphs

If I have a simple graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, then I want to create a randomly induced graph $G_x$ by selecting vertices with a probability of $n/2m$. The edges of $G_x$ are defined to be all $e\in E(G)$ between $u$ and $v$ where vertices $u, v \in V(G_x)$. How can I find the expected number of edges in $G_x$?

I started by calculating the expected number of vertices in $G_x$ as $n^2/2m$ and so the expected number of edges should be the probability that both $u,v\in G_x$ and $uv \in E(G)$. But this expected value is difficult to calculate. Can I have some suggestions without explicit answers?

Comment: Pick one particular edge $uv$ in $ E(G) $. The probability of him being in $ E(G_x) $ is $ (n/2m)^2 $. This is true for each edge, so by linearity of expectation value, the expected number of edges in $ G_x $ will just be $ (n/2m)^2 | E(G) | $.

Comment: I understand that we have the probability of each edge being there added together, but what is linearity of expected values, also this could serve as an answer not a comment for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in a comment, the expected number of edges is

$$
\left(\frac n{2m}\right)^2m=\frac{n^2}{4m}\;.
$$

For linearity of expectation, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity). The main thing to know about it is that it does *not* require independence. That's what makes it so useful – you can often easily calculate the expected value using the linearity of expectation when calculating the entire distribution and then using it to calculate the expected value would be very complicated due to correlations (as in the present case).